# Is join required on gevent gthreads?

Tags: gevent

Is a join required with gthreads, or can it just be used when blocking on a gthread is desirable?

Obviously, this is required with threads in most languages, but it seems like all documentation and discussions seem to omit this requirement, therefore implying that it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not required, but you'll generally want some sort of an implicit `join` else your program will exit after spawning each greenlet.

It's common to use a `while True` loop that performs other actions as the greenlets are running, or a `while` loop that will stop when each greenlet is killed, which achieves a similar effect. This basically leaves the greenlets to run in the background.

There needs to be some sort of blocking action between spawning greenlets and the end of the program, whether that be a `join`, a Python construct, or a call to something else.

Comment: I'm not referring to joins as a blocking mechanism. I'm talking about using them for required cleanup. Since greenlets aren't kernel-level resources, it didn't seem strictly necessary to join them. It sounds like you agree.

Comment: @DustinOprea You are correct, there is no need to clean them up. When the Python interpreter stops all greenlets will be dead.